# On the application of Modus Tollens rule

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 166, exercise B.2). When I enter this proof into an automatic checker, it says that application of MT rule is not correct ? Am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: I must warn you that forallx has a deep conceptual flaw in its deductive system for first-order logic. It has led to conceptual failures in many people who tried to learn from it, and they even cited forallx when explaining where they got their idea from.

Comment: Thank you, @user21820. Do you know where is its conceptual flaw ? Could you give me more details and recommend an alternative book, if possible ?

Comment: See [this comment I made in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/44058?m=44845324#44845324). I unfortunately don't know a good alternative book for Fitch-style deduction. The variant I personally prefer can be found from my profile under "Natural deduction", but it's not the conventional kind. But feel free to inquire further in [this chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics) if you like.

Comment: Thank you, @user21820. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the MT rule is *from $\alpha \to \beta$ and $\neg\beta$ infer $\neg\alpha$*, then to apply it here, with  $\alpha \to \beta$ the conditional $\neg N \to \neg M$, you will need the second input to MT to be $\neg\neg M$. Note the double negation!

So (if you *do* want a proof via MT) you will need to introduce the required double negation *before* you can apply MT and continue the proof, derive $\neg\neg N$ and then eliminate that double negation.

A general principle here: although in classical logic $\beta$ and $\neg\neg\beta$ entail each other, *every* time you want to move between $\beta$ and $\neg\neg\beta$ one way or the other [in a standard natural deduction system for classical logic] you do need to do the required little derivations. Why insist on this palaver? Because later you will meet non-classical logics with a non-classical understanding of negation where, in particular, you can't always make the move from $\neg\neg\beta$ to $\beta$ -- so you need to get used to the idea that there is a non-trivial [in some contexts, disputable] principle at stake in making the classically admissible move!

Answer (score 1):

You need as step 4 $\lnot \lnot M$ from 3. Then Modus tollens on 4 and 2 to get $\lnot \lnot N$. Then conclude $N$ (in two-valued logic).

Answer (score 1):

The MT rule of your text has the content of {($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$), $\lnot$$\beta$} $\vdash$ $\lnot$$\alpha$ as described on [p. 170](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf).  So, your proof checker matches your text in not allowing you to use MT in this way.

Instead of using MT though, you might show that (M$\rightarrow$N) holds since ($\lnot$N$\rightarrow$$\lnot$M) holds.

Comment: You mean $\alpha \to \beta, \neg\beta$ entails $\neg\alpha$.

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes!  Thanks for the correction.